# Ошибка (оператор, не применимый к данному типу операнда)

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Нужно сделать выбор даты рождения и сохранить в БД.
При запуске возникает ошибка

> [Error] Unit25.pas(193): Operator not applicable to this operand type

Что не так? Не могу разобраться
К dr применяла другие типы данных, выдает ошибку.

```
 dr:integer;

if (form25.Edit1.Text='')
or (form25.Edit2.Text='')
or (form25.Edit3.Text:=DateToStr(DateTimePicker1.Date))
or (form25.Edit4.Text='')
or (form25.Edit5.Text='')
or (form25.Edit6.Text='')
or (form25.Edit7.Text='')
or (form25.Edit8.Text='')
or (form25.DBLookupComboBox1.KeyValue='')
or (form25.DBLookupComboBox3.KeyValue='')
or (form25.DBLookupComboBox4.KeyValue='') then
  showmessage('Не все поля заполнены')
```

Comment: Давайте отформатируем ваш вопрос и код ..... так ошибку видно? ;-)

Comment: точка с запятой? или я не понимаю :D

Comment: Не знаю, где вы точку с запятой увидели .. двоеточие имеете ввиду? Ну да. Ошибка в том что в 3 строке вы не сравниваете значения, а делаете присвоение. Это в условии недопустимо.

Comment: точно, не заметила, сейчас попробую)

Answer (score -1):

можете сделать таким образом

```
(Length(edt1.Text)=0) or (Length(edt2.Text)=0) or (cbb1.Items[cbb1.ItemIndex]='') or (Length(edt3.Text)=0) then begin
      ShowMessage('Заполните поля!');
      Exit;
```

Comment: Что-то у вас совсем ничего с вопросом не совпадает. Да и ошибку вроде нашли (опечатка)